# How to track user activity like who is creating what resources on azure of a specific subscription?

Tags: azure, azureportal

In my company we have one Azure subscription and there are two or three users which are added on the same subscription and have right to create any resource on Azure.

Now since three users are working on same subscription and they are independently creating resources, I want to keep track or see which user created what resource on the same subscription.

Please let me know is there any way to see this tracking/activity details corresponding to the user.

Currently all users have administrator role/permission.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs):

> The Azure Activity Log is a log that provides insight into the
>   operations that were performed on resources in your subscription

Comment: But it has a limitation of past 90 days so how can I see the same based on resource ?

Comment: Thats the only service I am aware of to retrieve these information. You can also archieve the activity log as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-archive-activity-log

Answer (score 1):

The Activity Logs provides customers a Portal and REST API experience to see who performed what management operations (PUT/DELET/POST) through Azure Resource Manager (ARM) for the past 90 days.

For anything older than 90 days, you have the option to archive the data to storage account or stream the data to Event Hub if you would like to ingest this data into your own system.

The Activity Log data is also available through the Operations Management Suite.
http://www.deployazure.com/management/operations-management-suite/azure-activity-log-analytics-alerts-with-operations-management-suite/